# Issue with PRing from Hotfix into Dev branch

Tags: c#, git, azure-devops, git-flow

My source control experience is primarily in TFS and I have just recently joined a team working in GIT.

We seem to be experiencing an issue with our PRs into our dev branch using the standard git flow system for all hotfixes and releases.

Illlustration of the issue:

Today, as a test,  we cut a hotfix branch off of master.

First we pulled the latest code from master

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

And then we cut the branch

```
"git checkout-b hotfixtest".
```

I then made no changes at all to this hotfix branch and pushed it up to origin

```
git push origin hotfixtest
```

I then made a PR request into Dev.

In doing so, azure devops shows the hotfix branch and the dev branch changes and seems to indicate that changes exist in several files in dev.

Here is a screenshot to illustrate what we are seeing with the left hand side being hotfix and the right hand side being dev.  As you can see it appears many lines were added to dev that do not exist in hotfix.

[image]

This is the problem we are facing.

When I then pull the hotfix branch code and review it in visual studio i can see that in fact the files in both hotfix and dev  match the right hand side above. Both branches contain all of the date code.

So the mystery is why then is Git indicating the file is different and changed when we PR into dev.

Here is the file from hotfix showing that it matches the file in dev above.

[image]

**Edit/Update:**

Here is additional information.  We have found what is causing this issue but are unsure if this is proper.  The issue occurs for us anytime we we cut a release branch following the standard gitflow branching model.

**Heres what is happening.**

We cut a release branch off of development in preparation of release.

We test this code and we then merge it into master.

Now all of our latest code goes into master (lets say 20 file changes).

We then merge this release branch also back into development so that any bug fixes found during release testing get merged back into dev.

At this time the code changes to master (20 files) are far greater than the code changes merged into dev because the release branch was cut off of dev and is 99% identical. Only bug fixes made in release get merged back into dev.

Now, if we cut a hotfix off of master and attempt to PR into dev, git is going back to the original changeset where both master and dev were in sync and showing us the changes from that changeset rather than the code changes between the hotfix and dev branches.

This makes it so that we are unable to see the code changes being made in a hotfix when we PR into dev and seems to leave the "files" section of our devops PR unusable.  If we have made 1 file change in the hofix we may see 20 files showing up with changes even though they match in dev and the hotfix branch.

Comment: Are you creating PR to merge from hotfix to master branch or dev branch. If you have to merge changes to dev branch then you should create hot fix from dev branch not from master branch.

Comment: as with all hotfixes in gitflow, the hotfix gets cut off of master (because you are resolving an issue in production) and then gets merged to both master and dev branches so that both production and local development get the defect resolution.

Comment: Have you tried deleting QA and just remaking it from master?

Comment: because developers actively work in dev we have not tried deleting the dev branch and recreating it. However, i feel like this may be something we look at. Additionally it looks like rebasing from master may be a way to sync it up correctly to stop this issue.